# Check if there are .format files in a directory

Tags: python, file, directory

I have been trying to figure out for a while how to check if there are .pkl files in a given directory. I checked the website and I could find ways to find if there are files in the directory and list them, but I just want to check if they are there.

In my directory are a total of 7 .pkl files, as soon as I create one, the others are created so to check if the seven of them exist, it will be enough to check if one exists. Therefore, I would like to check if there is any .pkl file.

This is working if I do:

`os.path.exists('folder1/folder2/filename.pkl')`

But I had to write one of my file names. I would like to do so without searching for a specific file. I also tried

`os.path.exists('folder1/folder2/*.pkl')`,

but it is not working neither as I don't have any file named *.pkl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the python module `glob` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html)

Specifically, `glob.glob('folder1/folder2/*.pkl')` will return a list of all .pkl files in folder2.

Comment: I'd use `iglob` instead of `glob` and put that in an `any`, i.e. `has_plk = any(glob.iglob(os.path.join(dir_path, '*.plk'))`; it does *just* the required test.

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
for dir_path, dir_names, file_names in os.walk(search_dir):
        # Go over all files and folders 
        for file_name in file_names:
            if (file_name.endswith(".pkl")):
                # do something like break after the first one you find
```

Note : This can be used if you want to search entire directory with sub directories also

In case you want to search only one directory , you can run the "for" on os.listdir(path)